# jquery select all button with checkboxes issue

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a checkbox field corresponding to every row of a table that I output using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html) plugin. With this field check users can publish/delete .etc en masse. Thus I have a select all button. The issue is that after changing the paging back and fourth between a low and high number some things may remain checked that shouldn't. So I simply want the checkboxes to reset to the default unchecked value when the user changes the paging. I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.check').toggle(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).text('Uncheck all')
    }, function () {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).text('Check all');
    });
    $('.pagesize').change(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $('a.check').text('Check all');
    });
});

<a href="#" class="check btn">Check All</a>
  <select class="pagesize">
    <?php echo arrayToSelect($pageSize, '5'); ?>
  </select>
```

**It works however, whenever the user changes the page size, you have to click the 'check' button twice to get the select all feature to work again. Any idea what the issue may be?**

You can view the issue by changing the page size, then trying to click "Check All"

http://jsfiddle.net/H7SJd/

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test that instead:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H7SJd/4/)

```
$(function () {
    $("table")
        .tablesorter({
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra']
    })
        .tablesorterPager({
        container: $("#pager")
    });
});
/* my version
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.check').toggle(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).text('Uncheck all')
    }, function () {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).text('Check all');
    });
    $('.pagesize').change(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $('a.check').text('Check all');
    });
});
*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.check').click(function (e) {

        var txt = $(this).text();
        if (txt === 'Check All') {
            $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);            
            $(this).text('Uncheck All')
        } else { $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
            $(this).text('Check All');
        }
    });
    $('.pagesize').change(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
        $('a.check').text('Check All');
    });
});
```

Comment: You could want to use e.preventDefault() to avoid page scroll to top on click link if your page has scrollbar

Comment: tested still a bug after change page, i'll fix it

Answer (score 1):

Check DEMO here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/H7SJd/5/

```
$(function() {
        $("table")
            .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
            .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
    });
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.check').click(function () {        
        $('input:checkbox').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
                $('a.check').text('Check all');

            }
            else{
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                $('a.check').text('Uncheck all');
            }
        });
    });
    $('.pagesize').change(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $('a.check').text('Check all');
    });
});
```